# How do I hide this tooltip in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: annoying pop-up]

I've already tried the suggestions online that say to add the code below to settings.json but that disables something I *actually* want to have and not this annoying pop-up.

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 0):

When the pop up appears, hit `Ctrl + Space` again (assuming you are using `Ctrl+Space` to show intellisense to toggle additional information.